# My discord bot wont send text in server channels

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot to be easier for my friends to use my program.
But i ran in to this issue where the bot wont send any text in a server text channel.

1.It works in DMs

2.The bot is online and working

3.The bot has all the permissions needed

4.The bot receives the messages from the text channels and recognizes which text channel it was sent from

Can anyone help me find what the problem is?

Here is the code

```
import aiohttp
import discord
import asyncio
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

# Define your intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()

# Explicitly enable privileged intents that require explicit opt-in
intents.members = True

# Create a client instance with your intents
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!generate_id'):
        print("Command recognized!")
        # Prompt the user for input
        await message.channel.send("What's your name?")

        def check(m):
            return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel

        try:
            name = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, I didn't get a response. Please try again.")
            return

        await message.channel.send("What's your height?")
        try:
            height = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, I didn't get a response. Please try again.")
            return

        await message.channel.send("What's your weight?")
        try:
            weight = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, I didn't get a response. Please try again.")
            return

        # Get the overlay image from user's message attachment
        await message.channel.send("Please upload the image overlay.")

        try:
            overlay_image = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60.0)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, I didn't get an image. Please try again.")
            return

        if len(overlay_image.attachments) == 0:
            await message.channel.send("Sorry, I didn't get an image. Please try again.")
            return

        overlay_image_url = overlay_image.attachments[0].url

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(overlay_image_url) as response:
                overlay_image_data = await response.content.read()
        with open('overlay_image.png', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(overlay_image_data)
        overlay_image_path = 'overlay_image.png'

        # Load the image you want to use
        image = Image.open("C:/HitmanIDGen/hitman.jpg")

        # Create a drawing context
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

        # Set the font size and type
        font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\HitmanIDGen\Raleway-Black.ttf", size=40)

        # Get the dimensions of the image
        image_width, image_height = image.size

        # Define the position to place the text
        name_x = 700
        name_y = 400

        height_x = 200
        height_y = 50

        weight_y = 150
        weight_x = 234

        # Generate the ID string
        id_string = "{}\n{}\n{}".format(name.content, height.content, weight.content)

        # Draw the text on the image
        draw.text((name_x, name_y), name.content, font=font)
        draw.text((height_x, height_y), height.content, font=font)
        draw.text((weight_x, weight_y), weight.content, font=font)

        # Add image overlay
        if overlay_image_path:
            overlay_image = Image.open(overlay_image_path)
            overlay_image = overlay_image.resize((331, 526))
            image.paste(overlay_image, (78, 245))

        # Convert the image to RGB mode
        image = image.convert('RGB')

        # Save the image with the overlaid text
        with open("output.jpg", "wb") as f:
            image.save(f, format="JPEG")

        # Send the output image
        with open("output.jpg", "rb") as f:
            file = discord.File(f)
            await message.channel.send(file=file)
```

I tried using `client.fetch_channel()` which worked, it recognized the channel, still it wont send any messages in a server.

i tried:

```
async def on_message(message):
    print('Message received in channel:', message.channel.id)
```

It worked, but still the bot wont send any messages.

Instead of `message.channel.send` i tried `await client.send_message(message.channel, ...)` with no success.

I tried `message.guild` still no success..

I tried many other things too but the bot still would not send any messages in a server text channel.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the bot had the `Member Intent` activated from the discord portal, I had to add a few lines that I found in the API reference.

```py
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
```

I am not sure if both are needed, but it works after adding the intents to the code.

Comment: The 3rd line is the same as line 2

Comment: @boez You're right, i was too tired to notice, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: np it can happen